# Error in function `WordList` in version 12.1

Tags: warning-messages, dictionary, linguistics

I want to list the number of different kinds of words in the English dictionary (Version 12.1 for Win10 (64-bit)):

```
WordList[ Language -> "English"] // Length
Length[WordList[#, Language -> "English"]] & /@ {"Noun", "Verb", 
  "Adjective", "Adverb", "Preposition", "Conjunction", "Pronoun", 
  "Determiner", "Interjection"}
```

[image]

When I specify the dictionary as an English dictionary, I get the following error message:

[image]

I want to know how to count all kinds of words in English Dictionary correctly.

Even if I change it to English in my preferences, the following error still appears:

[image]

Comment: On my Mac it works fine with v12.0.0, v12.1.1, and v12.2.0

Comment: @BobHanlon Maybe this error only appears in Win system.